# Iterate over Python list, preserving structure of embedded lists

Tags: python, list

Python newbie here. I'm trying to perform a basic function on a list containing lists of various lengths. Within these lists are tuples containing pairs of elements that I intend to use as ranges. I want to convert these elements into integers, and then create a new tuple with the integers, followed by `2`, which will represent the iterator.

I want `l`:

```
l = [[('100', '200'), ('300', '400'), ('500', '600')], [('100', '200')], [('100', '200')]]
```

To be replaced by `l_upd`

```
l_upd = [[(100, 200, 2), (300, 400, 2), (500, 600, 2)], [(100, 200, 2)], [(100, 200, 2)]]
```

This obviously doesn't work (and I couldn't figure out how to get the `2` placed as an element:

```
l1 = []
l2 = []

for pairs in l:
    for pair in pairs:
        l1.append(int(i[0]))
        l2.append(int(i[1]))

l_upd = zip(l1, l2)
```

EDIT: I would prefer to not use a list comprehension method, because I need to include an `if`, `else` statement. Some of the elements contain letters, and some are empty.

Something like the following is needed for these exceptions:

```
for pair in pairs:
    if pair[0].isdigit():
        addr_from.append(int(i[0]))
    elif pair[0].isalnum() is True and pair[0].isdigit is False:
        addr_from.append(re.sub(r'((?:[A-Z].*?)?(?:\d.*?)?[A-Z]+)(\d+)',r'\1%\2',pair[0]))
    else:
        addr_from.append(pair[0])
    if pair[1].isdigit():
        addr_to.append(int(i[1]) + 2)
    elif pair[1].isalnum() is True and pair[1].isdigit is False:
        addr_to.append(re.sub(r'((?:[A-Z].*?)?(?:\d.*?)?[A-Z]+)(\d+)',r'\1%\2',pair[1]))
```

Comment: "followed by `2`, which will represent the iterator." What? I have no idea what you're trying to say here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehensions:

```
>>> [[tuple(map(int, pair)) + (2,) for pair in pairs] for pairs in l]
[[(100, 200, 2), (300, 400, 2), (500, 600, 2)], [(100, 200, 2)], [(100, 200, 2)]]
```

Or without the map:

```
>>> [[(int(a), int(b), 2) for a, b in pairs] for pairs in l]
[[(100, 200, 2), (300, 400, 2), (500, 600, 2)], [(100, 200, 2)], [(100, 200, 2)]]
```

#### Edit

Even with further checks, you can still use list comprehension. I assume that the if/else section you have added to your question should be applied to every pair, and the resulting tuple would be `(addr_from, addr_to, 2)` then, right?

```
def processPair(a, b):
    if a.isdigit():
        a = int(a)
    elif a.isalnum():
        a = re.sub(r'((?:[A-Z].*?)?(?:\d.*?)?[A-Z]+)(\d+)', r'\1%\2', a)
    if b.isdigit():
        b = int(b) + 2
    elif b.isalnum():
        b = re.sub(r'((?:[A-Z].*?)?(?:\d.*?)?[A-Z]+)(\d+)', r'\1%\2', b)
    return (a, b, 2)
```

Here I have defined a function that processes the tuple `(a, b)` as you did in your question. Note that I have changed it to just modify the values of the variables and return a finished tuple (with the added 2) instead of appending it to some global list.

I have also simplified it a bit. `a.isdigit() is True` is the same as `a.isdigit()` as that already returns a boolean value. Same for `a.isdigit() == False`, which is the same as `not a.isdigit()`. In that situation you can also remove redundant checks. After checking `a.isdigit()` on the `if`, you do not need to check its opposite on the `elif`; it is guaranteed to be false, as you have already checked it before.

That being said, when you have said function, you can then use list comprehensions again, to get your output. Of course with your example `l`, this is a bit boring:

```
>>> [[processPair(*pair) for pair in pairs] for pairs in l]
[[(100, 202, 2), (300, 402, 2), (500, 602, 2)], [(100, 202, 2)], [(100, 202, 2)]]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks Poke!

Comment: Poke, it just occurred to me that my question was overly simplified. Because an if, else statement is needed, could you demonstrate how this would be represented without using list comprehensions?

Comment: A little neater: `[[(int(x), int(y), 2) for x, y in pairs] for pairs in l]`.

Comment: @user: that doesn't preclude a comprehension. What do you need the if/else to do?

Comment: "an if, else statement is needed" - you could ask a new question; but first see if you can't use an equivalent expression: `x if y else z` is an *expression* evaluating to `x` when `y` is true, and to `z` otherwise (but each term is evaluated at most once).

Comment: @user1185790 Please see my updated answer; I think you should be still fine with list comprehensions ;)

Comment: Ah, of course! Define the function first and then plug it into the list comprehension. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

you could write some recursive function to do the job(which means the function can deal with any level of nested lists unless it hits maximum recursion depth)

```
def addtwo(lst):
   new_lst = []
   for item in lst:
     if isinstance(item, list):
       new_lst.append(addtwo(item))
     elif isinstance(item, tuple):
       new_lst.append(item + (2,))

   return new_lst

l = [[('100', '200'), ('300', '400'), ('500', '600')], [('100', '200')], [('100', '200')]]
print addtwo(l)

#[[('100', '200', 2), ('300', '400', 2), ('500', '600', 2)], [('100', '200', 2)], [('100', '200', 2)]]
```

Comment: +1 for thoroughness. The level of depth won't be any greater than my example, but your answer may likely come in handy in the future. Thanks thkang!